# Outlook appointment default open in series for reminders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, reminder

I use outlook appointments to keep brief notes on my classes, I have a reminder on the classes when it is scheduled to start.
When I double click on the reminder it opens the single instance of the event not the series, I need to be able to get the series open (so I can easily see what we have done already).  Is there a way of doing this without closing the reminder, going to the calendar, double clicking and choosing series?

Also is there a way of making the default opening of an appointment go to series?

Thanks

(I'm using 2010, but I guess it is a universal 'feature')

Comment: The Reminder is 'reminding' you about the specific occurrence, not the series, so I doubt it's doable; but hey, maybe someone know a way. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in Outlook 2010:

1. Open the appointment instance from the reminder
2. Click "Appointment Occurrence" tab
3. Click "Edit Series".

The full recurring appointment can now be edited.

Comment: OP was not asking how to edit the entire series, but how to make the DEFAULT editing mode that of the entire series. In fact, reading the question again, OP already does exactly what your answer says, and specifically notes they are looking for something besides that. Please read questions clearly. It is OK to answer "this isn't possible" if you know that is not possible. But avoid posting answers that do not actually answer the question.